# Create new instance for every uploaded file

Tags: php, oop, orm, symfony

I'm new to Symfony and OOP.

Trying to create an App where users can upload files of their activities. Every User will have one or many activities. Every Activity will have exactly one file.

The User will just upload files and for every file I want to create a new Activity();

So I thought the Controller should look like this:

Detailed Files can be found here: https://gist.github.com/carambazza/53804469d3021601f1bb

```
// DashboardController.php
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $activity = new Activity();

        $form = $this->createForm(ActivityType::class, $activity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // form is valid ...
    }
```

.

```
// ActivityType.php
class ActivityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextType::class)
            ->add(
                'activityFile',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type' => ActivityFileType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                )
            )
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Upload .fit file'));
    }
```

.

```
// ActivityFileType.php
class ActivityFileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', FileType::class,
                array(
                    "required" => TRUE,
                    "attr" => array(
                        //"accept" => "image/*",
                        "multiple" => true,
                    )
                )
            );
    }
```

The mapping is like this:

```
// Activity.orm.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity repository-class="ChartsBundle\Repository\ActivityRepository" name="ChartsBundle\Entity\Activity">

    <id name="id" type="guid" column="id">
      <generator strategy="UUID"/>
    </id>

    <many-to-one field="user" target-entity="User" inversed-by="activities">
      <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </many-to-one>

    <one-to-one field="activityFile" target-entity="ActivityFile">
      <join-column name="activity_file_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </one-to-one>

    <!-- other connnections -->

    <!-- all fields -->

  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

.

```
//ActivityFile.orm.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity repository-class="ChartsBundle\Repository\ActivityFile" name="ChartsBundle\Entity\ActivityFile">

    <id name="id" type="guid" column="id">
      <generator strategy="UUID"/>
    </id>

    <!-- all fields -->

  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

**The Question(s):**

- Are the relations between the Objects allright like what they are?
- How can I get the file upload to work and to create a new instance of activity for each file? Users will be able to select multiple files for upload

Answer (score 1):

The form isn't right, for me. The collection type is for one-to-many relationships, for example if you wanted to add activities to your user inline whilst editing your user. For a one-to-one relationship, you want to embed the form for the activity file within the activity form, so instead of a collection type, you just need this:

```
->add('activityFile', ActivityFileType::class)
```

Your relationships look right. Would suggest your repository filename for your ActivityFile entity isn't consistent, should be `ChartsBundle\Repository\ActivityFileRepository` instead, but that's a minor complaint.

Comment: Thank you the form works now! Also the repository filename is now fixed I think in the ActivityFile.orm.xml as you suggested. Should I change the property `activityFile` to `activityFiles` for the Entity Activity? And change it to array() or something to get the multiple selected files?

Comment: Like now if I select a few files and submit the form I'll just get the last from selected files if I call `$activity->getActivityFile()` but I would like to create an Activity Entry and upload each selected file

Comment: @caramba as it's one-to-one, I'd leave it as activityFile. If you want to have multiple files per activity, you'll need to change the relationship to a one-to-many, at which point, your original collection type would be correct again. Depends what you want, one file per activity, or multiple files.

Comment: I want one file per activity. But I want to make it so User can select multiple files and if he does so: Let's say User selects 5 files, now I need to create 5 Activities (5x new Activity()) and each Activity contains the one file.. but I just don't know how I can accomplish that !?

Comment: Hmm. From my experience, there's no Symfony form type to handle multiple simultaneous uploads. The way I've done something similar (a gallery entity with multiple image entities, each of which has a file attached) is to use Dropzone.js in my frontend Twig template that POSTs files to an backend action that creates new entities as it receives them, deals with storage and then links those entities to the parent. Really easy to set-up, and probably the best solution for you in this use case. Can show you some example code if that would help.

Comment: Have forked your gist and updated the appropriate parts [here](https://gist.github.com/ajcerqueti/28201e8d050625d017c1).

Obviously I'd separate the JS etc, and I'm assuming you'll want to migrate the annotations to yml config (I prefer to use annotations in my projects), but that should hopefully give you a decent starting point to start pulling apart!

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! I'll try with it